Which HTTP Status Code for regularly changing destinations
I run a website for a movie theater. There should be the address cinema.com/flyer, which should always redirect to the current flyer of the month (flyer_may_2024.pdf, flyer_june_2024.pdf and so on).
Which HTTP status code is the right one to satisfy search engines and caching mechanisms? We have tried 302, but with varying success: some browsers redirected correctly, others redirected to the old destination.
Thanks for your help.

You might try status 303.
302 Moved Temporarily
303 Permanent Redirection

In this case, the target URL changes every month. Does this correspond to a permanent redirection?

I don't know why the target URL changes every month, but you might try 307.
See also link .
